# Query to get employee name and manager name that are from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery, common-table-expression

**Employee Table**

```
EmployeeNumber (PK)
PersonID 
ReportstoManagerEmployeeNumber (i.e.- the employee number of the employee's manager)
```

**Names Table**

```
PersonID (PK) 
FirstName 
LastName
```

I want to display FirstName, LastName, EmployeeNumber, ReportstoManagerEmployeeNumber , Firstname as managerfirstname, LastName as managerlastname

Basically I want to select the first name and last name of the ReportstoManagerEmployeeNumber column

What I have tried:

```
SELECT n.FirstName, n.LastName, emp.EmployeeNumber, 
    emp.ReportstoManagerEmployeeNumber, n.firstname as managerfirstname, n.lastname as managerlastname
FROM Names n
INNER JOIN employees emp
    ON n.personID = emp.personID
INNER JOIN employees emp2
    ON n.personID = emp2.personID
```

I was thinking a self-join but this won't work as this just selects the names of the employees from the first and second column. I am new to SQL but I believe a subquery or a CTE is required but I am not sure how to set it up.

To clarify-- John Smith has personID = 1 in the Names table but has employeeID = 2 in the employee table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the other way around, you need to join 2 Names tables one for the employee and one for the manager

```
SELECT 
    emp.EmployeeNumber,
    n.FirstName,
    n.LastName,
    emp.ReportstoManagerEmployeeNumber,
    n1.firstname AS managerfirstname,
    n1.lastname AS managerlastname
FROM
    employees emp
        INNER JOIN
    Names n ON n.personID = emp.PersonID
        INNER JOIN
    employees  emp2 ON em2.EmployeeNumber= emp.ReportstoManagerEmployeeNumber
        INNEr JOIN
    Names n1 ON n1.personID = emp2.personID
```

Comment: Not getting the expected results from this query because PersonID is not linked to EmployeeID. For example, John Smith has personID = 1 in the Names table but has employeeID = 2 in the employee table.

Comment: i see that your structure made for me not that much sense, but the principle  is the saem. only we need another employee table to link them together, as you see in the edited answer